# How to make linedit ready to be typed into when pushbutton is clicked

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlineedit, qpushbutton

In my program, the user has to regularly push a button and then type a number into linedit. Every time the user clicks the button they have to click on the linedit again so they can type into it. Is there a way to automate this process so when the user clicks the button, linedit is ready to be typed into.

Comment: When you are already able to listen on click events, you probably have already worked with signals and slots. There is just one connection missing for your desired behaviour. I'm sure, you will figure it out. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to invoke the setFocus() method of QLineEdit.
See the example below,

```
void MyWidget::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   ui->lineEdit->setFocus();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could manually give focus to the `QLineEdit` - see [QWidget::setFocus](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus).